# Django context dictionary DRY

Tags: python, django, django-views

So I'm going to preface that I'm new to Django and Python in general...
Nonetheless, I'm trying to figure out a better way to update my context dictionary within my views.  I have some DRY data that always should be passed, and data specific to the view I'm in.  Is there a better way than just using dictionary.update? Again, I'm looking for a more DRY approach.

```
def get_searchdata():
    # helper function to populate search info
    spec_list = Speciality.objects.order_by('name')
    ins_list = Insurance.objects.order_by('name')
    dict_data = {'Specialties': spec_list,
                'Insurances' : ins_list}
    return dict_data



def individual(request, provider_id):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    doc = Provider.objects.get(id=provider_id)
    context_dict = {'Provider' : doc}
    context_dict.update(get_searchdata())
    return render_to_response('search/individual.html', context_dict, context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some data that you want to be available in all templates throughout your site, you could create a ["context_processor"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext). This is simply a function that returns a dictionary. That dictionary is added to the context (and therefore available in your template) when rendering any view with a `RequestContext`.

In your example you would create a module in an app with a single function:

```
def get_searchdata():
    spec_list = Speciality.objects.order_by('name')
    ins_list = Insurance.objects.order_by('name')
    dict_data = {'Specialties': spec_list,
            'Insurances' : ins_list}
    return dict_data
```

and add it to your `settings.py` `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    ...
    "myapp.mycontext_processors.get_searchdata"
)
```

Now you will have access to that data (`Specialties` and `Insuraces`) in any templates that are rendered with a `RequestContenxt` (for example any view rendered with the shortcut `render()`)

Comment: Thanks Timmy.  That definitely makes sense.  The other question I have  is there any action I need to take to actually use those objects within my templates, or are they just there?  E.g., to I declare anything when I return from my view?

Comment: You just have to make sure that you are using a `RequestContext` and not a normal `Context` when rendering a template. That means making use of the `render()` shortcut etc. Once you do that, the variables will be available in your templates, you won't have to do anything else

Comment: So I seem to be getting an error with this:   `get_searchdata() takes no arguments (1 given).`  In my return I have the following:`def index(request):
    #return enumerated list for specialties and insurances
    spec_list = Speciality.objects.order_by('name')
    ins_list = Insurance.objects.order_by('name')
    context_dict = get_searchdata()
    #context = RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response('search/index.html', context_dict, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.  Was missing a parameter for request in my context function.